# Determine final size of element wrapper before jQuery effect (e.g. slideDown)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me if (and how) jQuery determines the final size of an element that is animated with the built-in effects functions like `slideDown()`?

To give a practical example http://jsfiddle.net/GgCLa/:

CSS:

```
#wrapper { display: block; }

#wrapper p {
     display: none;   
}

#wrapper p:first-child {
     display: block;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
       Curabitur et quam urna, ultrices commodo odio.</p>
    <p>Nulla at tellus augue, varius dignissim nunc. Donec mattis
       est quis sem iaculis scelerisque. .</p>
</div>
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Clickey" />
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").toggle(
        function() { $("#wrapper p:last").slideDown("fast"); },
        function() { $("#wrapper p:last").slideUp("fast"); }
    );
});
```

Is there a way to determine the final height of the wrapper before the animation has completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem with the Anthony Jack's help. To get the final size of the wrapper before the animation is fired, the height of all elements contained within the wrapper need to be summed like so:

```
var calcHgt=0;
$("#wrapper *").each(function() {
   calcHgt+=$(this).height();
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GgCLa/4/

Comment: Aha, glad you got it.  I realize now that you wanted the whole wrapper height.  For some reason(not sure why given the title) I was thinking that you wanted just the hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

[.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) and [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) both seem to return the height of the element in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ant_blaze/GgCLa/2/) even if the element is currently hidden.